# VisualStudioCode + php : specify "include path" for code completion

Tags: php, visual-studio-code, settings, include-path

New to php with VisualStudioCode, i'm searching a method (settings, extensions, ...) to add a path to include php library, for code completion only.

Let's say, for the example, that I'm working on a wordpress plugin.

My VSC working directory is `/Users/richnou/Documents/my-wp-plugin/` which contains only the plugins files (php, sass, css, gitignore, etc...) ; they are automatically sent to a development server.

With this configuration, all the core Wordpress functions are **Undefined function** (I have *PHP IntelliSense* and *PHP Intelephense* installed).

There is a way to specify folders that will be scanned for code completion and hints ? So, one Wordpress Code installed in a common directory (say, `/Users/richnou/Documents/wordpress/` for ex.), so *outside* of my directory. (Netbeans has this "include path" notion...)

Thank's in advance

Answer (score 1):

Problem here is that `Documents` folder is secured, so put plugin file on path `/Users/richnou/`
Solved my problem

Answer (score 1):

## TL;DR

Extension Settings => **"Intelephense › Environment: Include Paths"**

---

Generally - use a helper/checker/highlighter extension - these extensions usually come with a Setting of an "include path"(s).

As you said you're already using ["PHP Intelephense"](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=bmewburn.vscode-intelephense-client), this makes things much simpler:

1. (File => Preferences =>) Settings => Extensions => "intelephense"
2. **"Intelephense › Environment: Include Paths"**
3. Click on "add item", add the path you want and hit "ok" => that should be all.

**Important note:**

It didn't work for me with alias paths like `~/...`  - **use absoute paths like:** `/home/u/work/wordpress-6`

Side note:

If it doesn't work, make sure the path is correct and try to restart the IDE. It works for me without it though.

Answer (score 0):

One solution (not ideal but which works) is to go through a symbolic link to a local installation of Wordpress...

`ln -s /Users/richnou/Documents/wordpress/  wp`